# Crop thumbnail images - add_image_size - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am trying to add a thumbnail crop to images, however I can't get it to work correctly. I have faced similar problems earlier, but wasn't able to solve it.

The page shows the latest posts, and since some of them has different horatio and size, I must use thumbnail crop within functions to make them appear the same size and correct horatio, and not scale them into something different.

**This is the code I am using to show latest thumb**

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('frontpage_thumb');  } ?>
```

**Within functions.php:**

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
    add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size' );
function mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size(){
    add_image_size( 'frontpage_thumb', 300, 220, array( 'center', 'center' ) ); // Hard crop center
}
```

**The problem**

They thumbs resize, but don't crop. [See page.](http://www.vekvemedia.no)

I have tried *Regenerate Thumb Plugin*, but no result.

Have I misunderstood the *"WP cropping"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared to be related with the thumbnails with Wordpress.

**To solve the problem I did the following:**

- Uninstall the thumbnail plugin used
- Install another thumbnail plugin
- Regenerate